# Changing the ID of a model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a model called `Album` which `has_many :songs`. I would like a user to be able to move songs from one album to another. Messing around in the Rails console, I have found that

```
song.album_id=2
song.save
```

works fine, but, I am having doubts that this is the right way to apply it in a real application. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@album = Album.find_by_id(10)
#This is the album to move song
@song = Song.find_by_id(100)
#This is the song to be moved
@song.album = @album
@song.save
```

Comment: take note that the `update_attribute` skips any validations, checks, whatever, it replaces the attribute directly in the database

Answer (score 1):

Nothing unusual here:

```
song.album_id=2
# or
song.album = @album
```

Both do their job.

Answer (score 1):

By having these:

```
album has_many :songs
song belongs_to :album
```

You could do this:

```
#find your album, by params[:id] or any other means you wish

album = Album.find(params[:id])

#assign it to the song

song.album = album
```

This way you are making sure the album actually exists before assigning a song to it